# Undefined function 'lt' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

I store a list of 30k date information in variable 'enDate' of size/type <30000x1 cell> , each cell contains 11 chars string like this '01-Jan-2004'(eg.).

I want to filter out a list of true/false into trainInd, where the date is less than (before) '2007-01-01'. I try this way but matlab prompted error 'Undefined function 'lt' for input arguments of type 'cell'.' .

```
 trainInd = enDate < datenum('2007-01-01');
```

What is the right way to (a) compare date, and (b) filter the array offset in 1 line of code with the above structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arh OK. I tried this way and it works

`trainInd = datenum(enDate) < datenum('2007-01-01');`